# Regular Expressions to parse addresses

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I am trying to learn how to use regex to parse location/address strings.
Unfortunately the data that I have been given is inconsistent and unconventional to how most addresses are written. Below is what I have so far, the problem that I am having is I need to parse the string multiple time to get it down to the proper format.

Take the following string for example: `102 Spruce, 108 Spruce, 110 Spruce, Greenwood, SC 29649` the end result that I want is `110 Spruce, Greenwood, SC 29649`

### CODE:

```
l = nil
location_str = "102 Spruce, 108 Spruce, 110 Spruce, Greenwood, SC 29649"
1.upto(4).each do |attempt|
  l = Location.from_string(location_str)
  puts "TRYING: #{location_str}"
  break if !l.nil?
  location_str.gsub!(/^[^,:\-]+\s*/, '')
end
```

### OUTPUT:

```
TRYING: 102 Spruce, 108 Spruce, 110 Spruce, Greenwood, SC 29649
TRYING: , 108 Spruce, 110 Spruce, Greenwood, SC 29649
TRYING: , 108 Spruce, 110 Spruce, Greenwood, SC 29649
TRYING: , 108 Spruce, 110 Spruce, Greenwood, SC 29649
```

### EXPECTED:

```
TRYING: 102 Spruce, 108 Spruce, 110 Spruce, Greenwood, SC 29649
TRYING: 108 Spruce, 110 Spruce, Greenwood, SC 29649
TRYING: 110 Spruce, Greenwood, SC 29649
```

Comment: So you just want the last part of the input if there are multiple building numbers?

Comment: will the input always be address_1, address_2, ... , city, state, zip?

Comment: @Anthony not necessarily but this is the main case that I want to take care of. Out of the 700+ addresses I have to go through ~550 are passing, so if I can get that number a little bit higher I will be happy. Unfortunately the client doesn't know how to be consistent in anyway what so ever and to try every possible case would be insanity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those there's-more-than-one-way-to-do-it things. Here's yet another:

```
def address_from_location_string(location)
  *_, address, city, state_zip = location.split(/\s*,\s*/)
  "#{address}, #{city}, #{state_zip}"
end

address_from_location_string("102 Spruce, 108 Spruce, 110 Spruce, Greenwood, SC 29649")
# => "110 Spruce, Greenwood, SC 29649"
```

Comment: This got me a little closer and it might have to do.

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that the format is:

```
"Stuff you aren't interested in, more stuff, more stuff, etc., house, city, state zip"
```

then you just take the last 3 sections by anchoring to the end of the string using a dollar sign:

```
location_str[/[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*$/]
```

Comment: `String#scan` is for when you want multiple matches. When you just want one match, use `String#slice`, a.k.a. `String#[]`: `location_str[/[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*$/]`.

Answer (score 0):

An attempt without regex:

```
address = "102 Spruce, 108 Spruce, 110 Spruce, Greenwood, SC 29649"
elements = address.split(",").map(&:strip)
city, state_and_zip = elements[elements.length-2..-1]
addresses = elements[0...elements.length-2]

p [addresses.last, city, state_and_zip].join(",")
```

output:

```
"110 Spruce,Greenwood,SC 29649"
```

Comment: Instead of `elements[elements.length-2..-1]`, why not `elements[-2..-1]`? And instead of `elements[0...elements.length-2]`, `elements[0...-2]`? Regardless, this seems needlessly complex. Why not `city, state_and_zip = elements.pop(2); addresses = elements`?